# Typescript, allow duplicated files within the same Visual Studio project

Tags: typescript

I'm migrating work from one project to another. Within the project are two javascript files which have identical function APIs but different implementations, they are linked on different pages so there's never any danger of them overlapping.

I'm renaming these files as typescript and slowly migrating parts of them.

When I build the project I get errors because of duplicate definitions, is there any way I can tell Visual Studio to ignore these within these files?

Short of renaming every function what's the best way of dealing with this?

At the moment I'm thinking of keeping the js files, changing function names and changing back to typescript later

Comment: you could try putting those functions in different modules, and have each page import it's own.

Comment: Typescript newbie here, isn't that the same as renaming the functions? i.e. If, for example, you had <button onclick="Func()" wouldn't you have to change all the onclicks?

Comment: uhm.. it really depends on how your project is set up.